# How to update radio button's data to mysql database with php?

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, edit

CODE am trying:

what about update radio button's logic ?? Is this OK ??

```
            if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{   
    $book_save = $_POST['book_title'];
    $author_save = $_POST['author_name'];
    $gender_save = $_POST['gender'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE bookss SET book_title ='$book_save',author_name ='$author_save',gender='$gender_save' WHERE ID = '$id'")
                or die(mysql_error());
```

i refer 2 links in SO but m not getting properly with radio button .... 
Suggestions are always Welcome ...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with everyone above, are you hard coding the radio button values? if so, I'm not sure how SQL injection would effect radio button entries. In any case, if you're stuck to this structure I'd at least do something like this: 
`$book_save = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['book_title']);`

Comment: You can't think of a $_POST value as a "radio button entry". I can create a form on my site, or even locally on my computer, and have it post to your form, and attempt to inject different values for your radio buttons than what you hard code. For that reason, every element of the $_POST array should be validated/escaped before anything is used in a query string (unless you're using prepared statements).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct. I would suggest you escape your data though. You're open to sql injection. I'd also look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as the mysql functions are deprecated.